# How to assign a value to a DateTimeOffset data type

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

Sorry for the noob question, I am trying to learn TDD. I have a program that will check to see if a specific time is used. I have declared the time using the DateTimeOffset DataType and I am not sure how to reference it in the test. Here is the code I have.

Model:

```
namespace Attendance.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public string DayOfWeek { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set;}
        public DateTimeOffset Time { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Test Controller:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void FindByTimeSlotReturnsStudentsInSlot()
        { 
            // Arrange
            var StudentRepository = Mock.Create<Repository>();
            Mock.Arrange( () => StudentRepository.GetAll()).Returns(
                new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student {Name = "Bob Smith", DayOfWeek = "Monday", Time = "10:40:00" },
            new Student {Name = "Mike Jones", DayOfWeek = "Wednesday", Time = "11:20:00" },
            new Student {Name = "Mary Jane", DayOfWeek = "Wednesday", Time = "11:20:00" },
            new Student {Name = "Albert Einstein", DayOfWeek = "Tuesday", Time = "12:15:00" },
            new Student {Name = "Fred Flintsone", DayOfWeek = "Monday", Time = "10:40:00" },
        }).MustBeCalled();

            // Act
            HomeController controller = new HomeController(StudentRepository);
            ViewResult viewResult = controller.FindByDayOfWeek("Monday");
            var model = viewResult.Model as IEnumerable<Student>;

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(2, model.Count());
            Assert.AreEqual("Bob Smith", model.ToList()[0].Name);
            Assert.AreEqual("Monday", model.ToList()[0].DayOfWeek);
```

The error is on the Time = "10:40:00", which tells me that I cannot convert a DateTime to a string. I have also tried 10,40,00, (Unexpected interger) and 10:40:00 (Syntax error "," expected)

Any ideas would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Time property is not a DateTime; it is a DateTimeOffset.  Use that type's constructor to create an instance of the type:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx

```
...
new Student {Name = "Bob Smith", DayOfWeek = "Monday", Time = new DateTimeOffset(/*some arguments here*/) }
...
```

Comment: Tried that as well, gives you: 'System.DateTimeOffset' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments, or 6 arguments if you try to use the yr, mo, day, hr, min, sec example.

Comment: It seems, since you accepted the answer, that you've already figured this out, but for the record, all it requires is to use one of the 6 constructor overloads listed on the linked page.  These mostly require a TimeSpan argument to indicate the UTC offset.